# Perl use function visibility

Tags: perl

Address.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
pacakge Address;

sub new {
   my $package = shift;
   my $self = {@_};
   return bless $self, $package;
}

sub country {
    my $self = shift;
    return @_ ? ($self->{country} = shift) : $self->{country};
}

sub as_string {
    my $self = shift;
    my $string;

    foreach (qw(name street city zone country)) {
        $string .= "$self->{$_}\n" if defined $self->{$_};
    }
    return $string;
}

$test = Address-> new (
    name => "Sam Gamgee",
    street => "Bagshot Row",
    city => "Hobbiton",
    country => "The Shire",
);
```

test.pl

```
use Address;
$test = Address-> new (
    name => "Sam Gamgee",
    street => "Bagshot Row",
    city => "Hobbiton",
    country => "The Shire",
);

print $test->as_string;
```

It cannot find Address at the line use Address in test.pl
the two perl files are in the same folder.

What do I have to do for test.pl to see Address.pl?

Comment: Don't write Perl without `use strict; use warnings;`.

Comment: I used to post this, its tone is not the best so I don't anymore, but I don't have the time to type something better right now: http://joelslinux.blogspot.com/2011/06/use-strict-and-warnings.html :-)

Comment: @ealeon: The point of using them is that they stop you from doing stupid things. But free free to read the full documentation - http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The module should be stored in `Address.pm` (pm (for *Perl Module*) not pl) and you should spell `package` correctly.

See also [`perldoc perlmod`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Perl-Modules) for an example of a Perl module.